# XCUI Distributed UI Testing

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I am working on XCUI test automation for an application involving two devices- for instance a video call application.

Currently I have two projects- project A running device 1's automation and project B running device 2's automation.

Is there a way in XCUI to achieve this with a single project?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is not a way to coordinate 2 devices using XCTest.

With some effort, you could set up your own server that coordinates the actions between these 2 devices by pinging the server before each XCTest action to check the status of your other device.